# SQL query that finds repeated data in one column with different data in a second column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have data that looks like this:

```
ID   Date   Data
A    D1     123
A    D1     456
A    D2     123
```

What I'm looking for is a select statement that will pull all rows where ID and Date are repeated as a pair, but the data doesn't match. In this case, it would return the top two rows, because ID A and Date D1 are repeated as a pair, but the Data is different. The third row would not be returned because the ID and Date combination are not repeated.

Comment: what if there are three rows with that ID and Date combination?

Comment: Any number of repetitions would be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select *
from yourtable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable t2
    where t.id = t2.id and t.date = t2.date and t.data <> t2.data
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the "select 1" does?

Comment: @Deena -- nothing really, just returns 1 or null... the `exists` statement checks to see if the `where` criteria matches.  In this case, you compare that the ids are equal and the dates are equal but the data is different.  Other methods including using `not in` or using self joins.  I prefer this and think it should have the best performance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with it and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  d.Id ,
        d.Date ,
        d.Data
FROM    YourTable d
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT Id ,
                            Date
                     FROM   YourTable
                     GROUP BY Id ,
                            Date
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                   ) a ON a.Id = d.Id
```